# Preventing multiple instances of a constructor function from sharing the same prototype properties

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Right when I thought I had a hold on how prototypal inheritance works in JavaScript, I run into an issue I hadn't before considered.

Take a look at the following simple JavaScript code:

```
var Observable = function () {
  this.events = [];
};

Observable.prototype.addEvent = function (e) {
  this.events.push(e);
};

var Model = function () {};
Model.prototype = new Observable();

var appModel = new Model();
var taskModel = new Model();

appModel.addEvent('Hello');
taskModel.addEvent('World');
```

Looking at either `appModel.events` or `taskModel.events` yields the same array: `['Hello', 'World']`. What I am looking to do is have each new `Model` have its own `events` array in as clean a fashion as possible. The following implementation of `Model` works:

```
var Model = function () {
  this.events = [];
};
Model.prototype = new Observable();
```

However, as more properties are added to `Observable` this becomes more unwieldy. I thought I could fix this as follows:

```
var Model = function () {
  this.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
};
Model.prototype = new Observable();
```

Alhtough as I'm sure those of you who are more experienced in JavaScript realize this throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`.

In summary I am looking for a way for each new `Model` to inherit properties from `Observable` and for each `Model` to have its own `events`. I realize that this is very class-like, but I would like to know how to do this using only JavaScript prototype-based inheritance.

It is worth noting that I have looked at Dean Edward's Base.js. The following works:

```
var Observable = Base.extend({
  constructor: function () {
    this.events = [];
  },
  addEvent: function (e) {
    this.events.push(e);
  }
});

var Model = Observable.extend({
  constructor: function () {
    this.base();
  }
});

var appModel = new Model();
var taskModel = new Model();

appModel.addEvent('Hello');
taskModel.addEvent('World');
```

But the following *doesn't*:

```
var Observable = Base.extend({
  events: [],
  addEvent: function (e) {
    this.events.push(e);
  }
});

var Model = Observable.extend({
  constructor: function () {
    this.base();
  }
});

var appModel = new Model();
var taskModel = new Model();

appModel.addEvent('Hello');
taskModel.addEvent('World');
```

Besides the point, I would like to learn how to do this with JavaScript prototypes using no class libraries.

Comment: And the question is.....?

Comment: I was having this exact problem trying to build an Observable class. Surely we can't be the first to build this sort of thing in JS?

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood here is that you want each instance to have their separate events array, If so follow the answer:

```
function Model(){
  this.events = [];
  this.addEvent = function(eventName){
    this.events.push(eventName);
  };
  this.getEvents = function(){
    return this.events;
  }
}

var m1 = new Model;
var m2 = new Model;
m1.addEvent("eve-1");
m2.addEvent("eve-2");
m1.getEvents(); //["eve-1"]
m2.getEvents(); //["eve-2"]
```

In your case you are adding events directly to the `prototype` not the instances hence they are added across all the instances...I hope this should help

Comment: What I am trying to do is get common behavior across multiple types of objects which share that common behavior. Although I did not create anything but `Model`, the intention is to create more types which share the same functionality, but not the same events. Keeping the methods on the `Observable` prototype makes sense to me but I want a way to not have to declare `this.events = [];` in every constructor function I create.

Comment: All those things that needs to be common should be added to prototype, and those variable events should be added as above...

Answer (score 0):

I had tried this to fix my problem:

```
var Model = function () {
  this.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
};
Model.prototype = new Observable();
```

The actual solution is to do this:

```
var Model = function () {
  Model.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
};
Model.prototype = new Observable();
```

This will give each `Model` its own `events` array as well as give each `Model` any other properties that the `Observable` constructor creates. The small overhead here is that `Model.prototype.events` is an empty array that is never accessed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your first bit of code there causes each instance of `Model` to have a common `events` array is because they have a prototypical reference to a single common instance of `Observable`. In other words, by doing

```
Model.prototype = new Observable();
```

You are basically telling JavaScript "make all instances of `Model` act like **this specific instance** of `Observable`".

There are a couple of different ways to correctly perform prototypical inheritance in JavaScript. If you can get by with the recently standardized ECMAScript 6, you can use the handy new `class` and `extends` keywords designed for this very purpose.

```
class Observable {
    constructor() {
        this.events = [];
    }

    addEvent() {
        this.events.push(e);
    }
}

class Model extends Observable {
    // Model definition
};
```

Unfortunately support for ECMAScript 6 still [isn't great](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility). ECMAScript 5 added [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which has been the preferred method of doing inheritance since (at least as far as I'm aware).

```
var Observable = function () {
    this.events = [];
};

Observable.prototype.addEvent = function (e) {
    this.events.push(e);
};

var Model = function () {
    Observable.call(this);
};
Model.prototype = Object.create(Observable.prototype);
```

MDN has a pretty nice [article on OOP in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) using this technique.